# Latest VS Mac updates causes SIGSEGV at SetContentView(resourceid) in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, debugging, crash

After updating VS Mac last week I now get a crash while running my app in debug mode. This is an existing app that has had no recent changes, and to be certain it is not a code change I loaded up a past build in source control and ran that with the same affect. I have tracked it down to calling `SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);` in the `OnCreate()` method of one of my `Activities`. This is not the first activity to show in the app, there is a log in activity that has no issues. But on my main page, the app dies without catching on an exception catch point. The crash happens regardless of device, but only in debug mode. And I can always launch the app directly from the device after it has installed and crashed. In my application output I get the below log which has not proven to be helpful. This is driving me nutty, please help, anyone!

```
[mono-rt] /proc/self/maps:
[mono-rt] 12c00000-52c00000 rw-p 00000000 00:05 34637 /dev/ashmem/dalvik-main space (region space)_1589_1589 (deleted)
[mono-rt] 6f2a1000-6f2b8000 rw-p 00000000 fd:03 393357 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot.art
[mono-rt] 6f2b8000-6f53a000 rw-p 00000000 fd:03 393358 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-core-oj.art
[mono-rt] 6f53a000-6f640000 rw-p 00000000 fd:03 393361 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-core-libart.art
[mono-rt] 6f640000-6f675000 rw-p 00000000 fd:03 393363 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-conscrypt.art
[mono-rt] 6f675000-6f6b2000 rw-p 00000000 fd:03 393364 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-okhttp.art
[mono-rt] 6f6b2000-6f6b6000 rw-p 00000000 fd:03 393366 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-legacy-test.art
[mono-rt] 6f6b6000-6f6f9000 rw-p 00000000 fd:03 393368 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-bouncycastle.art
[mono-rt] 6f6f9000-6f734000 rw-p 00000000 fd:03 393370 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-ext.art
[mono-rt] 6f734000-70056000 rw-p 00000000 fd:03 393373 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-framework.art
[mono-rt] 70056000-7010d000 rw-p 00000000 fd:03 393375 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-telephony-common.art
[mono-rt] 7010d000-70116000 rw-p 00000000 fd:03 393377 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-voip-common.art
[mono-rt] 70116000-7011e000 rw-p 00000000 fd:03 393379 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-ims-common.art
[mono-rt] 7011e000-70142000 rw-p 00000000 fd:03 393381 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-apache-xml.art
[mono-rt] 70142000-7016e000 rw-p 00000000 fd:03 393383 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-org.apache.http.legacy.boot.art
[mono-rt] 7016e000-70173000 rw-p 00000000 fd:03 393385 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-smartbondingservice.art
[mono-rt] 70173000-7017a000 rw-p 00000000 fd:03 393387 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-sprengine.art
[mono-rt] 7017a000-7017b000 rw-p 00000000 fd:03 393389 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-android.hidl.base-V1.0-java.art
[mono-rt] 7017b000-7017e000 rw-p 00000000 fd:03 393391 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-android.hidl.manager-V1.0-java.art
[mono-rt] 7017e000-70188000 rw-p 00000000 fd:03 393393 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-timakeystore.art
[mono-rt] 70188000-70191000 rw-p 00000000 fd:03 393395 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-fipstimakeystore.art
[mono-rt] 70191000-70192000 rw-p 00000000 fd:03 393397 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-ucmopensslenginehelper.art
[mono-rt] 70192000-70196000 rw-p 00000000 fd:03 393399 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-esecomm.art
[mono-rt] 70196000-70197000 rw-p 00000000 fd:03 393401 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-SemAudioThumbnail.art
[mono-rt] 70197000-701d1000 rw-p 00000000 fd:03 393403 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-knoxsdk.art
[libc] Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xbc in tid 23274 (OS_GETTAGS_CALL)
```

If I go to android monitor and use ***logcat***, I don't get much more:

```
04-09 09:32:59.458: E/mono-rt(25118): /proc/self/maps:
04-09 09:32:59.458: E/mono-rt(25118): 12c00000-52c00000 rw-p 00000000 00:05 34637 /dev/ashmem/dalvik-main space (region space)_1589_1589 (deleted)
04-09 09:32:59.458: E/mono-rt(25118): 6f2a1000-6f2b8000 rw-p 00000000 fd:03 393357 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot.art
04-09 09:32:59.458: E/mono-rt(25118): 6f2b8000-6f53a000 rw-p 00000000 fd:03 393358 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-core-oj.art
04-09 09:32:59.458: E/mono-rt(25118): 6f53a000-6f640000 rw-p 00000000 fd:03 393361 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-core-libart.art
04-09 09:32:59.458: E/mono-rt(25118): 6f640000-6f675000 rw-p 00000000 fd:03 393363 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-conscrypt.art
04-09 09:32:59.458: E/mono-rt(25118): 6f675000-6f6b2000 rw-p 00000000 fd:03 393364 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-okhttp.art
04-09 09:32:59.458: E/mono-rt(25118): 6f6b2000-6f6b6000 rw-p 00000000 fd:03 393366 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-legacy-test.art
04-09 09:32:59.458: E/mono-rt(25118): 6f6b6000-6f6f9000 rw-p 00000000 fd:03 393368 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-bouncycastle.art
04-09 09:32:59.458: E/mono-rt(25118): 6f6f9000-6f734000 rw-p 00000000 fd:03 393370 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-ext.art
04-09 09:32:59.458: E/mono-rt(25118): 6f734000-70056000 rw-p 00000000 fd:03 393373 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-framework.art
04-09 09:32:59.458: E/mono-rt(25118): 70056000-7010d000 rw-p 00000000 fd:03 393375 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-telephony-common.art
04-09 09:32:59.458: E/mono-rt(25118): 7010d000-70116000 rw-p 00000000 fd:03 393377 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-voip-common.art
04-09 09:32:59.458: E/mono-rt(25118): 70116000-7011e000 rw-p 00000000 fd:03 393379 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-ims-common.art
04-09 09:32:59.458: E/mono-rt(25118): 7011e000-70142000 rw-p 00000000 fd:03 393381 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-apache-xml.art
04-09 09:32:59.458: E/mono-rt(25118): 70142000-7016e000 rw-p 00000000 fd:03 393383 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-org.apache.http.legacy.boot.art
04-09 09:32:59.458: E/mono-rt(25118): 7016e000-70173000 rw-p 00000000 fd:03 393385 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-smartbondingservice.art
04-09 09:32:59.458: E/mono-rt(25118): 70173000-7017a000 rw-p 00000000 fd:03 393387 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-sprengine.art
04-09 09:32:59.458: E/mono-rt(25118): 7017a000-7017b000 rw-p 00000000 fd:03 393389 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-android.hidl.base-V1.0-java.art
04-09 09:32:59.458: E/mono-rt(25118): 7017b000-7017e000 rw-p 00000000 fd:03 393391 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-android.hidl.manager-V1.0-java.art
04-09 09:32:59.458: E/mono-rt(25118): 7017e000-70188000 rw-p 00000000 fd:03 393393 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-timakeystore.art
04-09 09:32:59.458: E/mono-rt(25118): 70188000-70191000 rw-p 00000000 fd:03 393395 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-fipstimakeystore.art
04-09 09:32:59.458: E/mono-rt(25118): 70191000-70192000 rw-p 00000000 fd:03 393397 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-ucmopensslenginehelper.art
04-09 09:32:59.458: E/mono-rt(25118): 70192000-70196000 rw-p 00000000 fd:03 393399 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-esecomm.art
04-09 09:32:59.458: E/mono-rt(25118): 70196000-70197000 rw-p 00000000 fd:03 393401 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-SemAudioThumbnail.art
04-09 09:32:59.458: E/mono-rt(25118): 70197000-701d1000 rw-p 00000000 fd:03 393403 /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-knoxsdk.art
04-09 09:32:59.459: A/libc(25118): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xbc in tid 25282 (OS_GETTAGS_CALL)
04-09 09:32:59.493: E/propClient(25287): PropClient failed to load
04-09 09:32:59.521: A/DEBUG(25288): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
04-09 09:32:59.521: A/DEBUG(25288): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/star2qltesq/star2qltesq:8.0.0/R16NW/88888:user/release-keys'
04-09 09:32:59.521: A/DEBUG(25288): Revision: '14'
04-09 09:32:59.521: A/DEBUG(25288): ABI: 'arm64'
04-09 09:32:59.521: A/DEBUG(25288): pid: 25118, tid: 25282, name: OS_GETTAGS_CALL >>> com.wallet.consumer <<<
04-09 09:32:59.521: A/DEBUG(25288): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xbc
04-09 09:32:59.521: A/DEBUG(25288): Cause: null pointer dereference
04-09 09:32:59.521: A/DEBUG(25288): x0 0000000000000000 x1 00000074b53a6648 x2 000000749b6f7178 x3 0000000000000008
04-09 09:32:59.521: A/DEBUG(25288): x4 0000000000000000 x5 0000000000000002 x6 00000074a1bdea98 x7 0000000000000009
04-09 09:32:59.521: A/DEBUG(25288): x8 00000074b53cc898 x9 0000000000000001 x10 0000000000000001 x11 0000000000000000
04-09 09:32:59.521: A/DEBUG(25288): x12 0000000000000276 x13 0000000000005540 x14 000000000000000d x15 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaab
04-09 09:32:59.521: A/DEBUG(25288): x16 00000074ab6849c0 x17 00000074c656cd00 x18 0000000000000001 x19 000000749b6f7178
04-09 09:32:59.521: A/DEBUG(25288): x20 00000074b53a6648 x21 0000000000000000 x22 00000074bb162e86 x23 000000749f47eeb0
04-09 09:32:59.521: A/DEBUG(25288): x24 0000000000000000 x25 00000074a7ddf700 x26 0000000000000000 x27 0000000000000000
04-09 09:32:59.521: A/DEBUG(25288): x28 0000000000000000 x29 000000749b6f7160 x30 00000074ab4db484
04-09 09:32:59.521: A/DEBUG(25288): sp 000000749b6f70d0 pc 00000074ab4db494 pstate 0000000060000000
04-09 09:32:59.521: A/DEBUG(25288): backtrace:
04-09 09:32:59.521: A/DEBUG(25288): #00 pc 0000000000199494 /data/app/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-bgZa5Uoa74W6pXDFoMuSZw==/lib/arm64/libmonosgen-64bit-2.0.so
04-09 09:32:59.521: A/DEBUG(25288): #01 pc 0000000000199480 /data/app/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-bgZa5Uoa74W6pXDFoMuSZw==/lib/arm64/libmonosgen-64bit-2.0.so
04-09 09:33:00.211: E/adbd(8161): recv: OPEN 00000261 00000000 000c:73 68 65 6C 6C 3A 70 73 20 2D 41 00
```

Comment: Having the same problem and have yet to find a solution. Seemingly it happends at random, have not been able to locate a source.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround that seems to be working:
[image]

Changing the HttpClient from **Default** to **AndroidClientHandler** solved the issue for me

Comment: Correction, did not solve the problem, only reduced it. Still happening jsut more rarely after i hcanged http client for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to update incase more people are having trouble.
The VS team are aware of the issue and as of 2 hours ago they have a potential fix that they are testing and finalizing so hopefully we will be able to download a fixed version shortly. for updates check
[this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/515603/android-crashes-every-time-with-the-new-vs-for-mac.html)